# Is there any way to optimise this code that uses pandas to read a TSV file, do transformations and write to a table using spark?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

```
    df_pandas = pd.read_csv('filepath/filename' , delimiter='\t' , encoding = 'utf-8', error_bad_lines=False )

    #defining the schema for the spark dataframe
    df_schema_file = StructType([StructField("Col1", StringType(), True),StructField("Col2", StringType(), True)])

    spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df_pandas,df_schema_file)
    spark_df = spark_df.withColumn("CreatedOn", lit(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())))
    spark_df = spark_df.withColumn("CreatedOn", spark_df["CreatedOn"].cast(TimestampType()))
    spark_df.write.mode('append').saveAsTable('tbl_name')


    #Creating dataframe from existing table
    spark_df = spark.table('tbl_name')
    df_name = spark_df.toPandas()
```

I am using the above code to read a TSV file, create a permenant table with the data in Databricks. This is why the conversion to spark dataframes is necessary. I also have to add the created timestamp to the table and specify the Timestamp datatype. I do not want it to be taken as string.

Then i need to create a pandas dataframe from the table so i can do some simple transformations on the data. The pandas dataframe should be made from the existing table.

Right now, this piece of code takes 2.48 minutes to run in databricks. Its too much as this used to complete in under 6seconds when i do not use the code to create a new timestamp column and specify its datatype.

Is there any way to optimise this code? 
I do not know if there is any way to directly save a pandas dataframe as a table. Hence the conversion to spark dataframes. And i need to do the transformations in Pandas dataframe itself. And i dont know any method to create a pandas dataframe from the table directly. Hence first to spark and then to pandas.

Is there any way to optimise this code?

Comment: Input file has 728868 rows.

Comment: spark_df = spark.table('tbl_name')
df_name = spark_df.toPandas()                            If i remove this code, it completes in 20seconds.

Answer (score 0):

There is two concepts in Spark that you need to understand first:

**Transformations** - That means lazy operations that creates one or more other RDDs. That means nothing is actually executed just planned. [Reference](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-transformations.html)

**Actions** - that produce a non RDD result like your `toPandas()` this actually executes all the planning with the transformations. [Reference](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-actions.html)

And about the time of execution, Spark has a really huge overhead to start the execution of any task. But it get a better performance when it is related to bigger tasks. There is a lot of cases that spark will be slower than pandas or numpy. But when you reach a specific case of Huge data the execution of Spark will by faster than any local execution. If you are running with a single machine with a small dataset like yours, pandas will be faster. Spark need to start a Session, find nodes, serialize data and etc. That is why you have this overhead. Keep learning and try with files of 100GB or more to see the performance.

Comment: Thank you Thiago for your comment. I am quite new to Databricks. Started just 3weeks ago.

Comment: I was wondering if there was any way to create a hive table straight from Pandas and create pandas dataframe from an existing table, so that the conversion from Pandas dataframe to spark dataframe and back can be avoided.

Comment: Pandas is not distributed by default. You should start working with the queries that Spark give to you. What pandas does spark do the same but distributed. The problem will be the syntax but you can get used to it.

Comment: Thiago, is there any way to make Pandas distributed?